# How do I cover up the color of my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, color

I have recently gotten a "old" macbook 12" (from 2018) from a family member, unfortunately the color is rose gold. It doesn't look that bad, but I would prefer a darker/space grey color. Is there any way I can cover up the rose gold color? I am wel aware of skins or slim cases, but non of those cover up every bit of the macbook (for example the edges of the screen or the space between the keys). If not everything is covered up I find it more ugly then the original and so not worth it for me. So I am looking for an other option to hide the color completely.

The reason I would like this change, is that it is now a pretty feminine computer and not a man's.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: You could commission a company like [ColorWare](https://www.colorware.com/) to do it for you.

Comment: Indeed a good idea, thanks! I will look into that, but I think it will be a bit to expensive for me.

Comment: The color of a laptop does not signal its user's masculinity, any more than a human's color determines their humanity. What defines "feminine"? Pink was considered a masculine color for quite a long time. https://www.cnn.com/2018/01/12/health/colorscope-pink-boy-girl-gender/index.html
In short, it's cheaper and easier to shift your viewpoint than it is to change the color of your mac.

Answer (score 1):

[This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/q5KTN_MYoF4) uses the

> air-dry, specialty rubber coating. In fact, it's the original peelable, flexible, insulating, non-slip, durable rubber coating

[Plasti Dip®](https://plastidip.com/our-products/plasti-dip/) to color the macbook black.

You have to clean the macbook very well before application, and you will have to mask every key on the keyboard, the screen, and your ports of course. Be careful.

The YouTube video says

> you're going to want to let it set for at least 24 hours out of direct sunlight in a room that is room temperature

I'm sure you can find other colors of air-dry spray-on rubber coatings.

Obviously the downside to this method is that your Macbook will no longer feel like metal, and will not look like metal either.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is get skins for the keyboard and trackpad and case, but I’m not a fan of these, even the best ones are hard to get perfect and painstaking if you need to cover all the color.

- https://keyshorts.com/collections/laptop-skins

[ColorWare](https://www.colorware.com/) used to customize macs, but they have stopped all “mail what you own in” services indefinitely. The first time I saw their work on a Mac it was “stop the presses” “mind-shatteringly” good quality and detail.

I would see if you can swap. I have the space gray MacBook one and it needs a new SSD so someone that needs a repair might be willing to step for close to equal cost based on color preference. Maybe someone out there is really disappointed and wishes they had rose gold?